# Same Session, Different Browser

Tags: php, session

I'm storing **actively changing data** in user sessions, **which requires consistency** for the user even if they log in with another browser or PC and end up with a new PHP-generated session_id

To counter this issue (and for other reasons) I store a username and session_id data pair in a maintained dedicated database, then after session_start() do something like (simplified):

```
$saved_sessid=$db->querySingle("SELECT sessid FROM sessions WHERE user = '".$user."'");
if(!empty($saved_sessid)){
 session_write_close();//dump newly generated session
 session_id($saved_sessid);//apply database-saved session_id
 session_start();//launch the already existing user session
}
```

Would this work as might be expected to make sure a particular user (based on logged in username) only has a particular PHP session or might it cause any unforseen issues, potentially security-related ones? I've been unable to find similar cases or test it reliably enough on my own and could do with some more experienced input

Comment: it will kind of work but i would suggest this: store the data against the clients id, then store that id in the session, so they can have 500 session variables (machines they are logged in to) but each will have the same client id and be extracting the data from one source

Comment: Without seeing your exact code, I've done this before and it works exactly as you'd expect. Note that there is a limit on how long PHP saves session variables though https://serverfault.com/questions/138214/are-php-session-files-ever-deleted

Comment: @nogad Do you mean storing the entire session in DB? That would require a full DB select and update for every page request that uses the session.

Comment: as opposed to a full file read on every page load?, its trivial to make a query on every page load almost every site does regardless of sessions.

Comment: I am voting down this question as it is not discussing any specific problem. It is more opinion-based.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi How is it "opinion-based" exactly? The "specific problem" is user session data consistency

Comment: Go through [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Point 4 for details.

Comment: @nogad I'm just saying it's unnecessary. A query to a database that hasn't been optimized will be magnitudes slower than a disk access, just think of all the overhead (connecting, authenticating, parsing etc). At least for sessions.

Comment: many sites use a db for sessions not files. i think your argument is invalid

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi I don't see the relevance. I'm not asking anyone to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource". "Instead", I "described the issue" and "what has been done so far to solve it"; exactly what it says at point 4.

Comment: @nogad Many sites also use <bold> tags, MD5 and don't use parameterized queries. Doesn't mean it's good practise or beneficial. Even so I'm doubtful you'll find any professional, quality site that uses a RDBMS for sessions, it's not standard practise and I've never worked on a site that did this.... Anyway this discussion is mute since we've both given our opinions to OP and I don't think either of us will conceded that one practise is better. o7 mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Xuzrus and nogad commented, essentially answering the "question", your method would work without any *added* unforeseen consequences, at least none directly. any data stored in the dropped session between `session_start()` and `session_write_close()` will of course be lost (i'm guessing you expected that), but the new user instance will then be "shared" with the "saved" session's data, with both "access points" processed in queue by php normally as if simply different pages

if you're using multiple instances of php (multithreading) i'm not sure though, i think php locking the session files in /tmp will make any risk of both clients wanting to use the session at the same time wait in line for ongoing processing to complete, but need confirmation on that